# Calculating average string length of a Column in Dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm lost on how I can calculate the average string length of any column in a dataframe using scala. I have been able to easily do it for numeric columns doing the following

```
val avgDF = df.dtypes.filter(x => x._2 == "DoubleType").map(ct =>avg(col(ct._1))).toList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

val findLength = udf { (ColValue: String) => ColValue.size }

```
  myData.dtypes.filter(x=>x._2=="StringType").foreach(f=>
  myData.select(avg(findLength(col(f._1)))).show()      
  )
```

Sample Data

```
Name|Age|email
Hari|12|hary@h0otmail.ocm
Hari|12|hary@h0otmail.ocm
Hari|12|hary@h0otmail.ocm
Hari|12|hary@h0otmail.ocm
Hasasasi|12|hary@h0otmail.in
```

Output

```
+-------------------+
|AVG(scalaUDF(Name))|
+-------------------+
|                4.8|
+-------------------+


+--------------------+
|AVG(scalaUDF(email))|
+--------------------+
|                16.8|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val avgDF = df.agg(mean(length(col("yourColumn"))))
```

Comment: My goal is to find the average string length for all columns of type String. This method won't work. I'm thinking that ill have to define a UDF possibly